# Exe - шник не работает с win 2000

Tags: devel-studio, php, exe

Скомпилировал программу на php devel studio.
На xp и 7 работает всё отлично! Но вот с win 2000 не работает не может найти библиотеку!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Он-то библиотеку находит, но не находит в ней заданный функционал. Скачайте последнюю версию этой самой библиотеки и положите ее в PATH (замените старую на новую). Перенесите с XP (я не думаю, что что-то испортится), но лучше все-таки установить Visual C++ Redistributables пакеты новые.

Comment: Я скачивал! Эта библиотека находиться в system32/ 
Её заменить нельзя так как win её использует! Ставлю её около самого exe шника, Всё равно не определяет!

Comment: Скачайте и установите Visual C++ Redistributables. Они содержат необходимые библиотеки и заменяют старые версии. Это самое стандартное и правильное решение проблемы.

Comment: А он будет работать с exe-шником devel studio ?

Comment: Вы не в ту сторону копаете. Здесь надо понимать, как устроена система Windows. Аппликация, написанная вами, запускается в среде Windows, соответственно использует некоторые предустановленные ресурсы, присущие этой системе. Т.е. понятие "будет работать с exe-шником devel studio" неверно звучит по определению.

Comment: Вот смотрите: сам Devel Studio запускается в среде системы и Ваша программа. Когда какая-нибудь программа запрашивает Shared библиотеку, то систему "указывает" ей путь до нее. По сути дела, установка Visual C++ Redistributables добавит в систему новые современные библиотеки и обновит, по мере необходимости, старые. Принцип обратной совместимости работает почти всегда - программы, использовавшие старые версии системных библиотек, будут работать и с новыми. Если нет совместимости, то система сама заботится об этом, сохраняя несколько несовместимых версий и "подставляя" нужную нужной программе.